# SQL UNION INNER JOIN

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, union, inner-join, union-all

Im trying to select from 2 tables that have the same columns, but both tables have an inner join -

```
select e.ID, 
    c.FullName, 
    car.VIN, 
    car.Registration, 
    e.Telephone, 
    e.Mobile, 
    e.Email, 
    e.EstimateTotal, 
    e.LastUpdated, 
    e.LastUpdateBy from (select id from Estimates UNION ALL select id from PrivateEstimates) e

inner join Customers c on c.ID = e.CustomerID
inner join Cars car on car.ID = e.CarID
where e.Status = 0
```

The trouble is, it can't find e.CustomerID, e.CarID or e.Status on the inner join? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Your subquery

```
select id from Estimates 
union all
select id from PrivateEstimates
```

returns only a single `id` column. Include necessary columns in the subquery if you want to use those columns in `JOIN` statements